# Emacs (AUCTeX) not writing to vc.tex file when using VC bundle in LaTeX document

Tags: emacs, auctex, mac

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.1 for Mac OS X on Lion with the latest version of AUCTeX and the VC bundle to print version information in a footer on my LaTeX documents. The problem is that when I typeset my LaTeX document, it runs the suggested shell command through `\immediate\write18{./vc}` just fine, but it's not writing anything to the `vc.tex` file when the vc script is run. I've checked the log file every time, and the following line always appears:

```
runsystem(./vc)...executed safely (allowed).
```

I've spent the better part of a day trying to figure out why the `vc.tex` file is not being revised, and I've narrowed it down to a problem with Emacs/AUCTeX because TeXShop seems to be doing it just fine. Alternatively, I can always run the vc script in Terminal, but I'd like to figure out why the `\immediate\write{./vc}` line isn't working in Emacs.

Any ideas??

Comment: Did you check that the `-shell-escape` option is used when running from emacs. You can see at the beginning of the `.log` file which command has been invoked.

Comment: I did check for the -shell-escape option. For the moment, I think I've figured it out. It seems that Emacs wasn't seeing my gawk executable file (in usr/local/bin), which it needs to run vc properly, and so nothing was being written to the vc.tex file. This was fixed by pointing Emacs to the gawk file through pandoc:

(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))
(load "pandoc-mode")
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'turn-on-pandoc)
(add-hook 'pandoc-mode-hook 'pandoc-load-default-settings)

Comment: At first I thought it was a problem with Auctex and I was trying to adjust the Tex-Command-List through customization, but apparently not.